# Java adding objects to an array from another class

Tags: arrays

I am trying to add an object to an ArrayList which is located in other class. I have setters and getters for the ArrayList but I cant add. Thanks in Advance.

```
public class Reservation {

    **Client client;**


Reservation(){
Client a = new Client (id ,name,surname,tel,email);
        **//need to add it here**
}


public class Client {

    int clientID;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    **public List<Client> clientList = new ArrayList<Client>();**
```

Comment: Why is clientList inside of Client??

Comment: Please be more specific about why you can't add to the ArrayList.  Do you have an error message or something?

Comment: Yes the error messsage is "The method setClientList(Client) is undefined for the type Reservation"

Comment: I have removed the ArrayList to Main but the problem didnt resolve.

Comment: Can you be more specific. Can you provide the exact code of both the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can you declare

```
public List<Client> clientList = new ArrayList<Client>();
```

inside your Client class. This should be declared in `Reservation` class. Your `Client` object cannot hold list of Client(s).

Answer (score 0):

a.clientList.add(new Client())?

Comment: sorry new to this site, how can I paste all my code? seems I cant change the original post once posted.

Comment: yeah you need a couple of upvotes before you can edit your posts. just post it in an answer, thatll work fine

Comment: public class Reservation {
 List<Client> clientList = new ArrayList<Client>();
 Client client;
 
 Reservation(){

  int id=1;
  String name="xillian";
  String surname = "van";
  int tel=02155454;
  String email = "questio@gmail.com";
  
  Client a = new Client (id ,name,surname,tel,email);
  clientList.add (a);
public class Client {
 
 public Client(int clientID, String firstName, String lastName, int tel, String email){
   this.clientID=clientID;
   this.firstName=firstName;

public static void main(String[] args) {

Comment: hmm cant post my code here it seems. anyways next time i will post it all in the main part. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, a reservation is for one client and this client has another guest clients. In this case, perhaps the best approach is your `Reservation` class be like that:

```
class Reservation{
    Client reserver;
    List<Client> guests;
}
```

or

```
class Reservation{
    int reserverClientId;
    List<Client> clients;
}
```

And you can do in the constructor:

```
public Reservation(List<Client> clients){
    this.clients = clients;
}
```

Comment: No its a hotel reception program. it takes the client info and creates a reservation for him.

Comment: Then why you need a list of clients?

Comment: A hotel can have many clients I need to store them somewhere to access them later on.

Comment: I think you need some more knowledge about Object Oriented Programming. The cohesion in this case demands another classes, like `Hotel` which have a list of `Reservation` and a list of `Clients`.